# How to change the format of multiple citings?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, ieeetran

I'm using:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}    
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\renewcommand{\citedash}{--}
\begin{document}
\cite{something1, something2, something3}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,bibliography}
\end{document}
```

I get: [1-3]. How can I get [1]-[3] instead?

Thanks

Comment: Just add the `nocompress` option to the `cite` package: `\usepackage[noadjust,nocompress]{cite}`. Mind this will give, `[1,2,3]` rather than `[1],[2],[3]` or `[1]-[3]`.

Comment: @Andrew but I want [1]-[3]!

Comment: You may want it, the people at IEEE apparently don't.

Comment: @Andrew people at IEEE gave me [1]-[3] in the proof read, mine was [1-3].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment the line `\renewcommand{\citedash}{--}`

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you can do this using `\citeform` from the 
[cite package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cite):

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\renewcommand\citeform[1]{#1}

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\cite{something1, something2, something3}

\begin{thebibliography}{10}
  \bibitem{something1} First reference.
  \bibitem{something2} Second reference.
  \bibitem{something3} Third reference.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

Comment: It does not work for me.

Comment: @Elnaz Somehow there was an extra `}` in the renewcommand line for `\citeform`.  I've removed this.

Comment: I've edited the post. The problem was the citedash command.